# How can I access the header of a response from Image.network?

Tags: flutter, image, http, http-headers

I load an image with `Image.network` from a server.
I get the filename of the image in the header. How can I access the header of the image?

I mean, `Image.network` sends a `get` request and becomes the filename in the header of the response. Is there a way for me to read the header?

Comment: no there is no way

Comment: There is no public method to get header data form `Image.network`. Maybe you can call a GET request and read the header from it

Comment: Sad, but apperantly true. Did the GET request thingy.